# Geocoder error in log but no geocoder configured or wanted

Tags: wordpress, error, geocoding

CiviCRM 4.7.31
WordPress 5.2.2

I get this error in the log file but don't have any geocoding provider selected (nor wanted) in Settings -> Mapping and Geocoding Providers.  I think this is happening when new contacts are entered.  It does not stop the contact from being entered successfully.

Any ideas what to change to stop this error (short of adding a geocoding provider, do not want that).

Message:
Aug 28 10:03:44  [error] Configured geocoder is invalid, must provide a format method
Array
(
    [geocode_class] => 
)

Answer (score 2):

You probably had it set to yahoo at some point, and then when yahoo was removed somehow the setting didn't get blanked out, so it's looking for the yahoo code files but they aren't there anymore. Did you try just re-saving the page at Mapping and Geocoding Providers with none selected? That should clear it.

Comment: Ah that makes sens!

Comment: I re-saved the page and haven't had the problem since then. Thanks!

Comment: Sadly the problem has reoccured so the resaving with none selected did not fix the message.

Comment: Do you have any extensions that implement geocoderFormat? Do a `grep -r geocoderFormat *` in your extensions directory.